# LG Hub Script Non-Functional

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

```
local Macro_Start = 3
function OnEvent(event, arg)
  if event == IsKeyLockOn("numlock")and arg == Macro_Start then
  EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true);
   PressMouseButton(1)
   repeat
     PressKey("d")
     Sleep(math.random(72000,73000)) 
     ReleaseKey("d")
     Sleep(math.random(100,200)) 
     PressKey("s")
     Sleep(math.random(1100,1400)) 
     ReleaseKey("s")
     Sleep(math.random(100,200)) 
     PressKey("a")
     Sleep(math.random(72000,73000)) 
     ReleaseKey("a")
     Sleep(math.random(100,200)) 
     PressKey("s")
     Sleep(math.random(1100,1400)) 
     ReleaseKey("s")
   until not IsKeyLockOn("numlock")
   ReleaseMouseButton(1)
  if event == IsKeyLockOff("numlock") and arg == Macro_Start then
      OutputLogMessage("Turn on NumLock")
  end
  end
end
```

Not sure why this isn't working, no errors popping up but when I press middle click it doesn't return "Turn on NumLock", and when i press numlock then middle click nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such function `IsKeyLockOff`.
You should use `not IsKeyLockOn` instead.

```
local Macro_Start = 3
function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == 'PROFILE_ACTIVATED' then 
        EnablePrimaryMouseButtonEvents(true)
    elseif event == 'MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED' and arg == Macro_Start and IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
        PressMouseButton(1)
        repeat
            PressKey("d")
            Sleep(math.random(72000,73000)) 
            ReleaseKey("d")
            Sleep(math.random(100,200)) 
            PressKey("s")
            Sleep(math.random(1100,1400)) 
            ReleaseKey("s")
            Sleep(math.random(100,200)) 
            PressKey("a")
            Sleep(math.random(72000,73000)) 
            ReleaseKey("a")
            Sleep(math.random(100,200)) 
            PressKey("s")
            Sleep(math.random(1100,1400)) 
            ReleaseKey("s")
        until not IsKeyLockOn("numlock")
        ReleaseMouseButton(1)
    elseif event == 'MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED' and arg == Macro_Start and not IsKeyLockOn("numlock") then
        OutputLogMessage("Turn on NumLock\n")
    end
end
```